# Can I convert an xPub key into a public key (address) using `derivePath` with `@solana/web3.js`?

Tags: web3.js

Can I convert an xPub key into a public key (address) using `derivePath` with `@solana/web3.js`?

Answer (score 2):

The solana web3.js package does not contain utilities for deriving new addresses in the BIP sense, only for deriving "program addresses", so you'll have to use some other library to do it.

Feel free to search on npmjs.org for packages involving BIP39, BIP44, or BIP32 depending on what you need.

More information about program-derived addresses at https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/calling-between-programs#program-derived-addresses